# How use ReactiveCocoa to move from first to last UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I want to use ReactiveCocoa in new project that I work on, nothing fancy because project is as always ASAP but I want to start learning this cool framework in practice. I have View that is ideal to implement as I thought something simple with ReactiveCocoa:

[image]

So after user will insert one number to first field, second field should become active, then third etc. I wrote this code:

```
_code = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:6];

[[_field0.rac_textSignal filter:^BOOL(NSString *value) {
    if ([value length] == 1){
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;

}] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    _code[0] = x;
    [_field1 becomeFirstResponder];
}];

[[_field1.rac_textSignal filter:^BOOL(NSString *value) {
    if ([value length] == 1){
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;

}] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    _code[1] = x;
    [_field2 becomeFirstResponder];
}];

[[_field2.rac_textSignal filter:^BOOL(NSString *value) {
    if ([value length]  == 1){
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;

}] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    _code[2] = x;
    [_field3 becomeFirstResponder];
}];

[[_field3.rac_textSignal filter:^BOOL(NSString *value) {
    if ([value length] == 1){
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;

}] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    _code[3] = x;
    [_field4 becomeFirstResponder];
}];

[[_field4.rac_textSignal filter:^BOOL(NSString *value) {
    if ([value length] == 1){
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;

}] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    _code[4] = x;
    [_field5 becomeFirstResponder];
}];

[[_field5.rac_textSignal filter:^BOOL(NSString *value) {
    if ([value length] == 1){
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;

}] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    _code[5] = x;
}];
```

It works fine when I first time insert characters but when I finish and for example select again first field things are getting messy - rest fields are reseting, I can sometimes insert more that 1 character etc.

I think I'm missing something basic here :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to accomplish what you want that is, I think, more in the spirit of ReactiveCocoa. Please bear in mind that I'm still fairly new to ReactiveCocoa, so there may be an easier way to do this. First create some fields:

```
UITextField *field1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 200, 44)];
UITextField *field2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 260, 200, 44)];
UITextField *field3 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 320, 200, 44)];

[self.view addSubview:field1];
[self.view addSubview:field2];
[self.view addSubview:field3];

field1.placeholder = @"field1";
field2.placeholder = @"field2";
field3.placeholder = @"field3";

NSArray *fields = @[field1, field2, field3];
```

Now, we're going to build some channels for the fields for later use. Be sure to look at the [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACChannel.h) for `RACChannel.` These are bound to their respective text fields' channels.

```
RACSequence *channels = [fields.rac_sequence map:^id(UITextField *field) {
    RACChannel *channel = [RACChannel new];
    RACChannelTerminal *terminal = [field rac_newTextChannel];
    [terminal subscribe:channel.leadingTerminal];
    [channel.leadingTerminal subscribe:terminal];
    return channel;
}];
```

Now, assuming our data comes out properly on the channels, let's collect the results, and bind to our `data` property. The call to `combineLatest` will wait to produce a value until all channel terminals have produced at least one value, and then will produce values for any channel terminal that produces a new value. The values are collect into an `RACTuple.` We then convert this to a sequence, and finally, an array, as that is what our property is that we are binding to. I print out the results for convenience.

```
RAC(self, data) = [[[RACSignal combineLatest:[channels map:^id(RACChannel *channel) {
    return channel.leadingTerminal;
}]] map:^id(id value) {
    return [value rac_sequence].array;
}] doNext:^(NSArray *contents) {
    [contents enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"Contents at index %ld: %@", idx, obj);
    }];
}];
```

Now, to handle switching between fields and updating their values, let's produce a signal of signals. First, let's zip the channels with their respective fields. For each, we return a signal that waits for the field to begin editing, and returns a tuple of the channel and field when that happens. We merge these signals, then call `switchToLatest` at the end so that we can get the latest inner signal for use below.

```
RACSignal *latestEditing = [[RACSignal merge:[[channels zipWith:fields.rac_sequence] map:^id(RACTuple *tuple) {
    RACTupleUnpack(__unused RACChannel *channel, UITextField *field) = tuple;
    return [[field rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin] map:^id(id value) {
        return [RACSignal return:tuple];
    }];
}]] switchToLatest];
```

When we subscribe to the `latestEditing` signal, we'll be notified when the field is editing. Once that happens, we want to wait for incoming values on the channel terminal corresponding to the text field. Note that we subscribe to the signal until the `UIControlEventEditingDidEnd` is received (the text field loses focus), so that we can dispose of it properly. Since the channel is conveying the latest text value to us, we need to edit it so that the field contains the last character entered. We send that value back on the channel terminal.

```
[latestEditing subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *tuple) {
    RACTupleUnpack(RACChannel *channel, __unused UITextField *field) = tuple;
    [[channel.followingTerminal takeUntil:[field rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd]] subscribeNext:^(NSString *string) {
        if ([string length] > 0) {
            [channel.followingTerminal sendNext:[string substringFromIndex:([string length] - 1)]];
        }
    }];
}];
```

Finally, we need to figure out when the focus should be set to the next field. We map the values from the `latestEditing` signal. Now, we return a signal that waits for the return key press (note the different event this time so that we don't do this if the user focuses to a different field via a touch event). That signal returns the next text field. Again, we call `switchToLatest` so that we can subscribe directly to the latest inner signal.

```
RACSignal *next = [[latestEditing map:^id(RACTuple *tuple) {
    RACTupleUnpack(__unused RACChannel *channel, UITextField *field) = tuple;
    return [[[field rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit] take:1] map:^id(id value) {
        NSUInteger currentIndex = [fields indexOfObject:field];
        NSUInteger nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;
        nextIndex %= fields.count;
        return fields[nextIndex];
    }];
}] switchToLatest];
```

Finally, set the proper field to become the first responder.

```
[next subscribeNext:^(UITextField *field) {
    [field becomeFirstResponder];
}];
```

Note that this solution can accommodate any number of text fields - to update the code all you need to do is add the new fields the the `fields` array in the correct order.

I'd suggest you take a look at the [ReactiveFormlets](https://github.com/jonsterling/ReactiveFormlets) project as a really nice example of how to use ReactiveCocoa.